# Azure Postgres Unable to create database - errors with must be able to SET_ROLE

Tags: postgresql, azure-postgres-database

We've set up a Azure Postgres database and are trying to run our database/schema/tables creations scripts. These script have worked fine on our VM/server based database hosts where we connect to the database as:

`sudo -u postgres psql`

But for AZ Postgres we connect remotely using:

`psql -h mypsql.postgres.database.azure.com -U admuser -d postgres`

Connection works fine, then we start our scripts which contain the following, and it fails on the `create database` step:

```sql
postgres=> create user rsm_user with login password 'test123';
CREATE ROLE

postgres=> create role rsm_role;
CREATE ROLE

postgres=> grant rsm_role to rsm_user;
GRANT ROLE

postgres=> create database rsm_db with owner = rsm_role;
ERROR:  must be able to SET ROLE "rsm_role"

postgres=> create database rsm_db with owner = rsm_user;
ERROR:  must be able to SET ROLE "rsm_user"
```

Looking at the differences between our local and AZ remote instance we see that is superuser locally is `postgres`:

```
postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 rsm_user  |                                                            | {rsm_role}
 rsm_role  |                                                            | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

On ZA remote:

```
                                                                                     List of roles
   Role name    |                         Attributes                         |                                                Member of                                                 
----------------+------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 admuser        | Create role, Create DB                                     | {pg_read_all_settings,pg_read_all_stats,pg_stat_scan_tables,azure_pg_admin,rsm_user,rsm_role}
 azure_pg_admin | Cannot login                                               | {pg_monitor}
 azuresu        | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 replication    | Replication                                                | {pg_use_reserved_connections}
 rsm_role       | Cannot login                                               | {}
 rsm_user       |                                                            | {rsm_role}
```

The local `postgres` user seems the equivalent of the remote `azuresu` user, and the remote `admuser` that we login as does not have the same level of privileges as `postgres`.

is there a way to connect as `azuresu` on the remote instance?

Or is that another step we need to to allow the `CREATE DATABASE` command to work?

Comment: Probably a code modification added by Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

Since the admin user we connect as was not a superuser, we found we had to :

`GRANT rsm_role to admuser`

before the `CREATE DATABASE` and then it work.